# Remove the editing cursor in the table's fields of Forms in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some Forms in my project which tables. Those tables has records, where I have on each line, some text fields (informational), and some buttons. When I select one of those lines with the mouse, by clicking on one of the text fields the editing cursor is always twinkeling in the field where I clicked. I would like that my mouse click only select the line in a color, and doesn't edit the field (This cursor is not a real edit, because it's impossible to really modify something to the edited text, but it would be more professionnal to remove it)

Any solution? (VBA/Access Form design,...) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a small (virtually invisible) control on the forms detail line. In each field you don't want them to settle on put a "got_focus" event that resets the focus to the virtually invisible control.

You can also use the on current event to set an unbound empty control to make the whole row change colour as per this explanation https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?p=1480574&postcount=6 . Ignore the very complex code shown initially in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge with a form in datasheet view.
What has worked for me, is using "On Mouse Down" event, like:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
MyTextBox.Enabled = False
MyTextBox.Enabled = True
End Sub
```